# How to embed app drawer / app launcher in Android Application

Tags: java, android, android-launcher

I'd like to embed the app drawer within an activity/layout in my android app. Has anyone seen an example of how this can be done?

I did a StackOverflow search and I wasn't able to find anything useful...

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=app+drawer

Comment: by app drawer, do you mean a drawer within your app - as in the Navigation drawer pattern? Or do you mean a drawer which contains a link to all the apps installed on the user's device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download [DevApps Direct](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inappsquared.devappsdirect) on your device. All the samples DevApps showcases are open source.

It has an example called "Sliding up Panel", with its code [here](http://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel).

But note that you'll also need to merge the code for this [gridview example](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/02/implement-own-app-launcher.html) if you want to replicate the listing of the launcher icons in that panel just like the app drawer does.

Comment: I'm having a few other issues with this build as well... mind taking a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913058/android-xml-layout-parameters-do-not-function-as-expected

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20911739/adding-a-textview-to-drag-and-drop-interface-android-java

Answer (score -1):

I basically think this is a bad idea you shouldn't be launching other apps from inside your app unless it is a launcher. That said I've written a few. Grab my source here https://github.com/aospTV/TVLauncher-Gee

Comment: I'm afraid this answer is packed with bad StackOverflow form. You invalidated the question, contradicted yourself, and placed all the actual value in your answer in a link, without context. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer