# Create an app drawer in android

Tags: android

Hi my problem is that I'm not familiar with the process of app drawer. Can you give me a guide on how to create an app drawer ? 
Links and codes would be much better.

Comment: Have a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20752269/how-to-embed-app-drawer-app-launcher-in-android-application

Answer (score 0):

Here's the design guidelines: https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

And developer docs: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Ahould have done a quick Google